# Override table display with flexbox bug in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, html-table, flexbox

**Updated answer**

The problem I had was coming from an old Doctype declaration which was preventing the display flex to work properly inside IE.
(Another "bug" on IE with table and display flex is that I had to force the display to block or flex on the td tags).

I leave my previous question here just in case someone has the same problem.

---

I'm totally stuck with this problem. I have tried a lot of things but none seems to be working.
I have to make an old HTML4 website more responsive, and it is full of tables.
Using flexbox I could remodel it somehow how I wanted but when I checked on IE, all flex rules seems to be totally ignored.

I tried a simple code to check flex rules on table, and I can't get it to work how I want it to.
(Both container should be displayed in the same way)

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
  <table>
    <tr class="container">
      <td class="child"> 1 </td>
      <td class="child"> 2 </td>
      <td class="child"> 3 </td>
      <td class="child"> 4 </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And here is the SASS:

```
table
    width: 100%
    table-layout: fixed
    display: block
    tbody
        display: block
.container
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    width: 100%
    margin: 10px
    .child
        height: 100px
        width: 100px
        box-sizing: border-box
        margin: 5px
        display: inline-flex
        align-items: center
        justify-content: center
        &:nth-child(1)
            background-color: lightcoral
            order: 1
        &:nth-child(2)
            background-color: lightgreen
            order: 0
        &:nth-child(3)
            background-color: yellow
            order: 3
        &:nth-child(4)
            background-color: lightpink
            order: 2
```

I spent so much time on this, I feel like I may be missing something really obvious here and hope someone can help me to solve this.

Comment: With your sample code, both are displayed the same on Chrome and IE11, so what is the issue? ... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/godGxG

Comment: I've already tried some tests on CodePen and as you said it displayed correctly. But if you create an html file and a css file on your drive and test it on IE, the table is broken.
(I think CodePen might be rendering the content on their side before sending it to the browser, hence altering a bit the real rendering, not sure about that though)

Comment: I tried that and it works fine in IE. And I hope you used a compiled SASS code? Here is a codepen with the html code I used: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ypxzrm

Comment: I found one of the reasons this happened...as I said at the top of the post, I'm refactoring an old HTML4 file. I compared my markup with yours and couldn't find a difference...except for the doctype declaration! 
I fixed the doctype and now the small code sample is working! 
(I still have a lot of bugs around flexbox right now so I can't really say it's totally fixed, but it was a huge step toward resolving this!)
Thanks a lot for your help !!

Comment: You're welcome. Since there is no IE Flexbox bug found, and it is unclear what _I can't really say it's totally fixed_ mean, either delete the question and post a new with updated info, or edit this one with a better title, new info and more specific code sample, showing what it is that still doesn't work.

Comment: I could check on the old files and it is indeed working.
I added a display block on the td tags when i first tried to solve this for IE but it wasn't working, so I deleted the display property and tried other stuff.
Fixing the Doctype and re-adding the display block on td tags solved this.

Answer (score -1):

I recently was stuck on a similar problem. I believe the issue in IE is specifically related to the 'width' property. Try adding 'max-width: 100%' for the container and 'max-width: 100px' for the child.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I just tried it and it's still not working.

The thing that amazes me in this problem, is that it's not only the flex direction that is not working, even the flex order is not working at all. 
It's like IE ignore totally the flex attributes of the container and child elements...